# How to solve XHR type error in console in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am unable to solve the "xhr type error" from console in Angular.js. While my full code is OK, I have check all the ng-href and ng-src tags. They are up to date.

Please find the error snapshot as well:

[image]

[image]

Comment: May we see the code that causes this, and the exact text you are receiving? What action do you take to receive this error? Is it on a browser console or your operating system console e.g. with NPM build tools?

Comment: yes it is in browser console!!!